react-multi-carousel is not rendering any item
I am trying to build a component using react-multi-carousel. I have double-checked that the library is installed properly. In inspect element, I have seen the CSS by the library but there are no items inside the "ul" of the carousel element.
Here is my implementation and the image of dev tools
import Carousel from 'react-multi-carousel';
import 'react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css';

// @mui
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';

export default function StudentInfo() {
  return (
      <Box>
      <Carousel
        additionalTransfrom={0}
        arrows={true}
        autoPlaySpeed={3000}
        centerMode={false}
        sliderClass="carousel-custom-class"
        className=""
        containerClass="container-with-dots"
        dotListClass=""
        draggable
        focusOnSelect={false}
        infinite={false}
        itemClass=""
        keyBoardControl
        minimumTouchDrag={80}
        pauseOnHover
        renderArrowsWhenDisabled={false}
        renderButtonGroupOutside={false}
        renderDotsOutside={false}
        responsive={{
          mobile: {
            breakpoint: {
              max: 400,
              min: 0
            },
            items: 1,
            partialVisibilityGutter: 8
          }
        }}
        rewind={true}
        // rewindWithAnimation={false}
        rtl={false}
        shouldResetAutoplay
        showDots={false}
        slidesToSlide={1}
        swipeable
      >
        {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((item) => (
          <Avatar key={item} sx={{ width: 100, height: 100, bgcolor: 'secondary.main' }}>
            P
          </Avatar>
        ))}
      </Carousel>
    </Box>
  );
}



